# version of Ruby for cucumber

Tags: ruby, macos, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have no knowledge in Ruby, but I need to run some tests in it. The code is in Ruby and Cucumber. I use intellij on Mac. When I first open intellij cucumber step definition where not recognised from feature file. In terminal I got:

```
Required ruby-2.1.2 is not installed. 
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.1.2"'
```

but

```
$ which ruby
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby
```

so I run the install command as suggested and now I get

```
$ which ruby
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
```

Now my feature files connected to step definition as well. I will appreciate if anyone could explain me what happened. What prompted me to downgrade the version of Ruby and how it fixed cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ruby 2.1.2 set in `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems`

What I suspect is happening is you have run `rvm use 2.1.2` in the terminal but when your IDE runs something it is using the ruby version set in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `.ruby_version` file in the project root directory. This will enforce a specific version of Ruby. So the person who put it there is who to ask why the version was restricted like that. There may have been a good reason, such as that's what is being used by all your users.

It has nothing to do with Cucumber. `rvm` has some kind of operating system hook, I think, that runs whenever you `cd` into a directory. It looks for its special control fiels such as `.ruby_version` and `.rvmrc` file. This page describes this in more detail: https://rvm.io/workflow/projects.